# disabled workflow still running

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Strangely even after un-checking workflow start options, it still fires when a primary workflow by email trigger. The workflow was save and publish multiple times but not working. It's a long workflow and recreating it would not advisable. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using Following steps

- Go to corresponding List's Setting and in list settings page click on "Workflow Settings"
- in Workflow settings page click on "Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow".
- Remove all previously running workflow instance.
- Try to republish the the workflow with modified triggering condition from SharePoint designer.

If still you don't see your changes getting reflected to site, Try publishing the same workflow with some other person's login ( I don't know the root cause for this but it worked for me several times. I guess this is how SharePoint Behaves).

Hope this solves your Problem.

.